# Is there a way to serialize an array of buttons in Windows Forms Applications

Tags: c#, arrays, serialization

I am trying to serialize an array of buttons to a binary file. I am aware that you cannot serialize individual buttons.

However, would it be possible to pass the buttons from the button array into a byte array and then serialize it. From there I could deserialize it when needed.

I am trying to save the button array as I want to be able to allow a player to save their game of checkers so they can return to it at a later stage.

Comment: A better design would be to keep track of the positions of the checkers in a data structure that is independent of the GUI.  Serializing and deserializing just the data you care about will be much easier than serializing GUI elements with all their display properties.

Comment: @adv12 So do you mean to create an array of some sort that contains strictly the data such as location etc of each individual tile?

Comment: Sure, a 2D rectangular array would be an appropriate in-memory representation of the board.  You could define an enum like `enum CheckerType { None, Red, Black }` and maintain a `CheckerType[,]` array in memory that you save in the format of your choosing.

Comment: I'll give that a go! Thanks I appreciate it. I will get back to you if it works.

Comment: @adv12 Thanks man for the idea, It works flawlessly as far as I can tell!

Comment: Glad to hear it!